# ftable() fails because r can't generate a table with more than 2^31 elements

Tags: r

i encountered a problem using the ftable() function in R. 
I basically have large data frames, where i want to delete all duplicated rows. Which is simply done with:

```
distinct(my_df)
```

I also want to count how many times a certain row does appear in the dataframe. which can be done with:

```
my_ftab <- as.data.frame(ftable(my_df))
my_ftab <- arrange(my_ftab[my_ftab$Freq>0,],desc(Freq))
```

This will return a data frame showing me the the distinct rows and how many times they occur..

When the size of my_df exceeds approx. 1000 * 30 it stops working because R cant produce data tables with more than 2^31 elements, which apparently would be necassary for some intermediate calculation step.

So my question is if there is a function that produces a similar output as ftable, but does not have its limitations?

Comment: `data.table` way: `setDT(my_df); my_ftab = my_df[, .N, by = names(my_df)]`. Should be much quicker.

Comment: Thank you so very much. The gain in performance is incredible.